# Rare Full Partition Behaviour

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

Yesterday, I had my main Linux partition more than 60% free.

Today, I tried to upgrade the system (as usual, each day) and it tells me: `There is not enough room to perform the upgrading. Please, free 70 GB at least.`

Then, I checked the partitions and... Effectively, really, the main Linux partition is almost full!

But... I didn't load (install) anything new!

I tried to free space with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get purge
sudo dpkg -l |grep -i ^rc
sudo dpkg -l |grep -i ^rc | cut -d " " -f 3 | xargs dpkg --purge
```

And... NOTHING! The system doesn't free anything.

At the same time, when I type `sudo -i` into the Terminal session, the system tells me:

```
Impossible to resolve the host 'my_user_name'
```

What's wrong here?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Run the Disk Usage Analyser on your root partition which should tell you what is using all of the space and potentially what is causing this.

Comment: Have you been manually updating kernels, and not deleting old ones?  I have seen this on my machines when I forget and have too many kernels installed.

Comment: Where is that "Disk Usage Analyser"?

Comment: Either search for `Disk Usage Analyser` in the dash or type `baobab` in a terminal session.

Answer (score -1):

This problem was almost auto-solved.

The problem began when a WineHQ (Windows) apps chrashes.

I think/guess/assume that some temporary hidden files used by that app, filled the partition.

I ran that app again and... "magically" the partition goes back to the original state (more than 70% empty).

The only one question still is in my mind is:

Is there a way to avoid this? ???